# SignalR lock button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr

I'm trying to implement a voting / like question system for a website with Asp.Net Core 3.0 with SignalR.
It's no problem to send the questions to the hub and add them to a questionList li element to display them in a list for every user at realtime.

There is a lock button, to disable the send button.
By clicking the lock button, the button on this page is disabled but only on this page and for no other user.

Here is my code:

Javascript

```
// LOCK QUESTIONS
document.getElementById("lockButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    lockQuestionsToHub();
});
 
function lockQuestions() {
    if (qstInput.placeholder == "Gesperrt") {
        qstInput.placeholder = "Frage...";
        qstInput.disabled = false;
        qstButton.disabled = false;
    } else {
        qstInput.placeholder = "Gesperrt";
        qstInput.disabled = true;
        qstButton.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Hub

```
public async Task SendLock()
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveLock");
        }
```

SignalR request handler

```
connection.on('ReceiveLock', lockQuestions);
 
function lockQuestionsToHub() {
    connection.invoke('SendLock');
}
```

Comment: If you want to disable only that page, why you are using SignalR?

Comment: It should lock for all users